# How to predefine file/directory parameter to xcopy

Tags: command-line, scheduled-tasks, task-scheduler, xcopy

I need to run xcopy command. But when I type it with all parameters:

```
xcopy \\<server>.<domain>.com\c$\Users\<user>\Documents\New_ADuser_mustang.ps1 C:\IAM\New_ADuser_mustang.ps1 /C /Y /R
```

I'm prompted with a question

```
Does C:\IAM\New_ADuser_mustang.ps1 specify a file name or directory name on the target (F = file, D = directory)?
```

I need to specify that before I run the command, not after that. The command is run as a part of automated daily task, so there is no one who could answer this question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### How do I force xcopy to assume the destination is a file not a directory?

Add an asterix `*` to the destination file name, like so:

```
C:\IAM\New_ADuser_mustang.ps1*
```

---

> When copying a single file with XCOPY, there is no option to indicate
>   if the destination is a filename or a directory (with the filename
>   defaulting to that of the source file).
>
> In such cases XCOPY will prompt with a (locale specific) message like:
>
> ```
> C:\> xcopy foo.txt bar.txt
> Does foo.txt specify a file name
> or directory name on the target
> (F = file, D = directory)?
> ```
>
> Adding a wildcard (*) to the end of the destination will suppress this
>   prompt and default to copying as a file:
>
> ```
> C:\> xcopy foo.txt bar.txt*
> C:foo.txt
> 1 File(s) copied
> ```
>
> This requires the source and target file extensions to be the same
>   length, typically 3 characters.

Source [Xcopy - Copy files and folders - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html)